# HP Proliant Microserver appears totally dead

Tags: hardware, hp-proliant

I have an HP Proliant Microserver (N54L G7) that has been sitting around  fully disconnected and turned off for about 2 years (but was happily running back then).

I wanted to repurpose it and today I added some RAM to it to start in on the path back to usefulness .  When I went to turn it on there was nothing - no lights, no fan, no spinning disks, no nothing. (and I now wish that I had powered it on *before* doing my upgrade)

I would have thought that if I had screwed up the motherboard during the upgrade that at least I would see some lights and/or fan action.  I even changed power cords on the rare chance that that was the issue.

There are now 4 areas that I can think of that could be problems but I don't know how likely they are:

1. <del>Battery has died, which is stopping the switch-on circuitry</del>  I just pulled out my meter and the battery is sitting at a happy 3V
2. I fried the motherboard during my upgrade
3. Caps on the motherboard have died (but nothing is visibly bad)
4. The PSU died for some reason.

My gut feeling is that it only makes financial sense to bring this  thing back from the dead if it is issue #1.

Any suggestions as what I should be looking at first?

Comment: Call HP. It's out of support, but they can still help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the thing is now working.

I suspect that taking the battery out, spending 10 minutes looking for where I put my meter (curtesy of recently re-arranging my office to be a lot neater), and measuring the battery to see that it was good gave the server enough time to reset whatever was locking up the power on circuitry.

Comment: whatever, I don't believe there was a battery issue. Without a charged battery you may receive a message during the startup process, but the machine will start in any way, at least some leds will turn on, fans will turn, etc. I believe there where an issue with the PSU. I have 2 of them at office - a olded colleague told me 1 of them is died, and I tried to debug the problem, but for my surprise is more than 2 months working 24/7 without problem. I hate HP (because personal reason XD), but I believe this microservers are very good (for what they do)

Comment: @HEDMON Believe what you want.  But the only difference between the server not working and the server working was removal of the battery.  Feel free to give a logical explanation as to how a PSU fault could explain the observed behaviour.

Comment: Hehe, can be, sometimes we have weird behaviors but the important is get it working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a server with N36L processor.
Removing the battery for cca 20 minutes fixed the problem. Replacing the PSU did not solve it.

The server was OFF for about 3 weeks, before that it was running for cca 5 years 24/7